# Find Public Facebook Videos

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

http://www.downvids.net/video/

I am trying to build an iOS app and having trouble trying to find the public links of facebook videos.

So in general i wanted to do what this website above is doing, show popular or new videos that are shared on facebook.

Can anybody guide me in right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you cannot search for videos, see the Search API documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/

Answer (score 0):

Yeah might be there are many ways to find latest videos on facebook. There are many facebook pages which are made for videos and on that pages video are post on daily bases. You get latest video from that pages and download it. But downloading video from Facebook is also a problem. Most of the Facebook video downloader are difficult to use. But i found a downloader which is very easy to use you also use it click [here](http://www.facebookvideodownload.info/). There are also some search tools which are use to find videos from facebook but i think it is one of the easy way.